# EF Core 3.0 - Linq 2 SQL could not be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

I had written following query, which was working in .net core 2.2

```
public static TEnt AddOrGet<TEnt, TKey>(this DbSet<TEnt> dbSet, TEnt entity, Func<TEnt, TKey> predicate) where TEnt : class
        {
            IQueryable<TEnt> exists = dbSet.Where(c => predicate(entity).Equals(predicate(c)));
            return exists.Count() > 0 ? exists.First() : dbSet.Add(entity).Entity;
        }
```

which I was using as following.

```
DocumentMetadata documentMetadata = new DocumentMetadata()
                {
                    Name = metadata.Key
                };

masterContext.DocumentMetadata.AddOrGet(documentMetadata, x => x.Name);
```

after upgrade to EF Core 3.0, it stopped working as per below bug reported.
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18020

Now how do I translate this so that EF core 3.0 can properly translate it to SQL?

In other words, how do I implement now AddOrGet method in EF-Core 3.0?

Comment: What does `ToLinqToDBTable()` do? What's the purpose of this entire method? You don't need to make any modifications to a `DbSet<T>` to query it. You don't need to *check* that an instance exists before attacing it - it's EF Core's job to detect whether it's a new entity or an existing one (based on the key's value) and generate the appropriate statement.

Comment: Without knowing what `ToLinqToDbTable()` does it's impossible to say what exactly in that method prevents EF from working. It's not needed though and perhaps the *easiest* way to fix this code is to remove all of it.

Comment: BTW the linked "bug" shows that the bug was in the application all along. EF Core 3 didn't break anything, it exposed the application bug. When that code worked it would *load all table rows in memory* before trying to filter them. That's *very* bad, especially if it ends up in production

Comment: ToLinqToDBTable() removed in question. that was linqdb.entityframework library, i was checking if that works or not and pasted here as it is without removing.

Comment: this method basically checks if entry already exists, then return that entry (so that i can use that id) else insert that entry. here i had checked if entry exists by "name" column check.